# Is my salary in UK taxable in India?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, india, salary

I have been moved to UK temporarily from India for 2 years. In whole 2013-2014 financial year, I am in UK and getting my salary in UK itself which is being credited in UK based bank. Will my income earned in UK in 2013-14 be taxable in India?
Note: I am transferring my savings from UK in my saving account in India.
Regards,
Devesh

Comment: First port of call should be the accounts department in your company. They would be dealing with these issues on quite a regular basis.

Answer (score 2):

No if you are outside of India for more than 183 days in a financial year, you are non-resident for tax purposes. Hence your income from UK is not taxable in India, from tax point of view, it makes no difference if you keep the money in UK or transfer to India.

Any interest you earn in India is taxable.